# building app after create-react-native-app

Tags: android, react-native, build, runtime-error

Ok, here is my problem ...

After creating a react-native app using command `create-react-native-app myApp`, I edited the file `App.js` and was able to run it on my android phone using `npm start` and the app **Expo**.

After that, I *eject* the project with `npm run eject`.

I tried to get the project to run from there in tree ways:

1. running `npm run android`,
2. running `react-native run-android`,
3. and opening the project under `myApp/android` with **Android Studio**, building it there.

Everytime I end up with the same error message on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S2):

> Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server.

Now after looking into this error message, I found the following "solution":

1. `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`
2. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

This resulted in the following error: `Cannot find entry file index.android.js`, since I used `create-react-native-app` which provides only the file `App.js`.

So I ran the command instead: `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file App.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`, which added the files `index.android.bundle` and `index.android.bundle.meta` to the `assets` folder.

Finally I ran:
 3. `react-native run-android` again.

Now I get the following error-message:

> Module AppRegistry is not a registered module (calling runApplication)

I'm out of ideas. Has anybody encountered a similar problem/knows how to deal with this?

Thanks,
Buugy

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

react-native 0.49.5 has an `index.js` file that needs to be used in the `react-native bundle` command.

1. `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`
2. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`
3. `react-native run-android`